# stripslashes inside Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to use the php stripslashes function inside a twig template but this function is not a standard twig function, so i have to add it to twig as an extension, i tried this code inside a controller, but it doesnt work:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class XController extends Controller
{

public function YAction($page)
{
$twig=$this->get('twig');
$twig->addFunction('functionName', new Twig_Function_Function('someFunction'));
...
```

do i need a use statement for the "Twig_Function_Function" class?
am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use it in your twig templates, you don't need to make any add or call inside your controller, Read the [How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) section of the documentation.

Basicaly, you need to create an [Extension Class](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#create-the-extension-class) that extends `\Twig_Extension` , then you need to [register it](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) as a service using the `twig.extension` tag. And finally you need to implement the [`getFunctions()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id2) method in order to add customized twig functions.

But in your case better is to add a filter, with the same logic you can also add a [`getFilters()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id3) method in your extension class so that you can specify your customized filters.

Also, take a deeper look at the [Extending Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) section of the documentation to understand all the ways twig can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

Or  `{{ function('stripslashes', "This\\'ll do") }}`

(or apply stripslashes() when building your Twig context)

But, also, if you do this in php:

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function(\Twig_Environment $twig) {
  $twig->addFunction(new Twig\TwigFunction('stripslashes', 'stripslashes'));
  return $twig;
});
```

Then this works in twig:

```
{{ stripslashes("This\'ll do...") }}
```